# Did Jesus use witchcraft when he said to Peter "before the rooster crows..."

Tags: witchcraft

I was listening to Derek PrInce speaking about nature of occult and witchcraft. He tells this story about Africans using witchcraft, there was one man who goes to a witch doctor so that he can get rid of his enemy. The witch doctor tells the man, when the Jacqual howls tomorrow, his enemy will no longer be there.

I understand similar thing have happened in bible.

New international version Mathew 26:34
"Truly I tell you," Jesus answered, "this very night, before the rooster crows, you will disown me three times."

Can we compare this statement of Jesus to witchcraft?  Can God do witchcraft?

Comment: To those who attributed demonic power to the Holy Spirit by which Jesus worked, Jesus gives the most severe warning in all of scripture : Matthew 12:30-32.

Comment: For it to qualify as witchcraft it has to first be manipulative, which is what witchcraft is by definition, manipulation and second using unclean spirits. Jesus did not manipulate or coerce Peter and Jesus was not using an unclean spirit to reveal this to Peter. So which part resembles witchcraft to you?

Answer (score 4):

Did Jesus use witchcraft when he predicted that Peter would disown him three times?

Before we go any further, perhaps we should define what we think witchcraft is.  Commonly, it is perceived as the practice of magic, especially black magic, involving the use of spells.  In some countries it is a religious practice involving magic and affinity with nature, usually within a pagan tradition.  Did Jesus resort to witchcraft in order to predict the manner in which Peter would disown him?  Hardly!

> There are only two sources of spiritual power: God and Satan. Satan has only the power that God allows him to have, but it is considerable (Job 1:12; 2 Corinthians 4:4; Revelation 20:2). To seek spirituality, knowledge, or power apart from God is idolatry, closely related to witchcraft. First Samuel 15:23 says, “For rebellion is as the sin of witchcraft, and stubbornness is as iniquity and idolatry.” Witchcraft is Satan’s realm, and he excels in counterfeiting what God does. When Moses performed miracles before Pharaoh, the magicians did the same things through demonic power (Exodus 8:7). At the heart of witchcraft is the desire to know the future and control events that are not ours to control. Those abilities belong only to the Lord. This desire has its roots in Satan’s first temptation to Eve: “You can be like God” (Genesis 3:5).

Why would Jesus, through whom all things were made, who is the light and the life of men and who opposes the darkness (John 1:3-5) resort to demonic, satanic powers of evil and darkness? Why would the very Son of God who came to earth to defeat those same powers have to draw his power from them?  The article from which the previous paragraph was extracted draws this conclusion:

> Any practice that dabbles in a power source other than the Lord Jesus Christ is witchcraft. Revelation 22:15 includes witches in a list of those who will not inherit eternal life: “Outside are the dogs, those who practice magic arts, the sexually immoral, the murderers, the idolaters and everyone who loves and practices falsehood.”  https://www.gotquestions.org/Bible-witchcraft.html

The Pharisees claimed that the miracles Jesus performed were done by the power of Satan.  Jesus drove out demons by the Spirit of God (Matthew 12:25-28) and condemned those who falsely accused him.  Jesus knew what was going to happen because he is God incarnate, God with us.

God condemns witchcraft and sorcery.  So does Jesus.

Answer (score 2):

No, the cock crow was a time in the early in the morning—when the cock crew. It referred to the shortness of time before Peter would betray Christ, despite his saying he would go to his death for Him (Matthew 26:35) a few hours prior. No witchcraft involved.